# How to setup for development of plone products

Tags: python, plone, buildout

I want to develop a few products for a defined Plone install/version, which I cannot change (3.3.5).

What is the best way to organize my source tree, so that I do not have to put a huge plone instance into source control that won't change anyway? I still want to use buildout for local checking, though...

What do you recommend?

I am on Windows and prefer git to hg, but can live with both...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is done now-a-days with `mr.developer`. You can use a buildout like this:

```
[buildout]
extends = 
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plock/pins/master/plone-4-3
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plock/pins/master/dev
```

And then add your sources to the `auto-checkout` parameter in the `[buildout]` section, and in the `[sources]` section, in the format described here:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer

Something like:

```
[buildout]
auto-checkout = my.package

[sources]
my.package = git https://url.to/my.package
```

Then add your package to the `eggs` parameter of the `plone.recipe.zope2instance` section as usual:

```
[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
eggs =
    Pillow
    Plone
    my.package
```

See the Plone coredev buildout for a working example:

- https://github.com/plone/buildout.coredev

And don't forget there is a `develop` parameter for the `[buildout]` section which allows you to specify the file system path to a "develop egg" (it does not perform a checkout though):

```
[buildout]
develop = src/my.package
```

Comment: I usually also put always-checkout = true in the [buildout] section so that my checkouts get updated automatically when I run buildout.

Comment: I also add "eggtractor" then you don't even need specify the "develop =" variables.   Just use `extensions += buildout.eggtractor`

Comment: I looked up the [mr.developer usage info](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer/#usage) and found that `always-checkout` indeed (as I hoped) refers to the `auto-checkout` packages. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by organize your source tree...

Regardless, you'll want to look over:

- http://plone.org/products/zopeskel for generating package structure
- http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual developer manual docs
- and http://collective-docs.plone.org/ community supplied howtos
- If you can, get Martin Aspeli's "Professional Plone Development" book also

The SCM you choose has nothing to do with Plone. Make that choice on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a buildout.cfg file in the root directory of your egg/product and extend the plonetest buildout from the collective:

```
[buildout]
extends =
    http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/buildout/plonetest/plone-3.3.x.cfg

package-name = collective.mypackage
```

This way you will only need to add two files (buildout.cfg and bootstrap.py) to your repository.

See http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.app.discussion/trunk/ for a full example.

If you develop more than one package though, mr.developer is probably the way to go.